# JavaScript reduce function issues

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, object, reduce

I am calling an API with JavaScript (Es6) which returns a JSON object.

First, example of my returned JSON here: https://pastebin.com/PrLc2pFD

Once I have the returned JSON as above, I am then using a map function to create a new object called array. I am using reduce to sum together some nested and repeated items.

Below is a snipped of my code:

```
var array = response.data.map(function(item, array) {


            var sumTaskTotal = item.jobTasks.reduce(function(sumTaskTotal, elem) {
                if (elem !== null && elem.sumTaskTotal !== null) {
                    return +(elem.total && elem.total.amountString ? elem.total.amountString : 0);
                }
            }, 0);

            var sumCostBillable = item.jobTasks.reduce(function(sumCostBillable, elem) {
                if (elem !== null && elem.totalCostBillable !== null) {
                    return +(elem.totalCostBillable && elem.totalCostBillable.amountString ? elem.totalCostBillable.amountString : 0);
                }
            }, 0);

            var sumThirdPartyCost = item.jobThirdPartyCosts.reduce(function(sumThirdPartyCost, elem) {
                if (elem !== null && elem.total !== null) {
                    return +(elem.cost && elem.cost.amountString ? elem.cost.amountString : 0);
                }
            }, 0);

            var sumInvoices = item.invoices.reduce(function(sumInvoices, elem) {
                if (elem !== null && elem.invoice !== null) {
                    return +(elem.invoicedNet && elem.invoicedNet.amountString ? elem.invoicedNet.amountString : 0);
                }
            }, 0);

    array = response.data.map(item => ({
      id: item.id,
      jobNumber: item.jobNumber,
      jobStateType: item.jobStateType,
      jobBillingStateType: item.jobBillingStateType,
      startDate: dateformat(item.jobStartDate, "yyyy-mm-dd"),
      internalDeadline: dateformat(item.internalDeadline, "yyyy-mm-dd"),
      potentialValue: item.potentialValue.amountString,
      estimatedValue: item.estimatedSellValue.amountString,
      billedNet: sumInvoices,
      sumTaskTotal: sumTaskTotal,
      sumCostBillable: sumCostBillable,
      sumThirdPartyCost: sumThirdPartyCost,
      jobDetailId: item.jobDetailId
    }));
```

The following reduce functions work fine:
**sumTaskTotal, sumCostBillable, sumThirdPartyCost**

What they are doing is checking to see if the fields exist, if so, then reduce and sum. If not, set to 0.

The one **not** working is:
**sumInvoices**

I cannot quite figure out why, I am not getting any errors, I am always just getting returned '0', as per the below **console.log(array)**

```
{ id: 2352162,
jobNumber: '2015T1151',
jobStateType: 'PROGRESS',
jobBillingStateType: 'NOT_BILLED',
startDate: '2017-07-26',
internalDeadline: '2017-07-24',
potentialValue: 190,
estimatedValue: 9500,
billedNet: 0,
sumTaskTotal: 9500,
sumCostBillable: 75,
sumThirdPartyCost: 11,
jobDetailId: 2679930 }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't return anything when the `if` test is `false`. A `.reduce()` callback must *always* return the target value.

Comment: *"if so, then reduce and sum"* - None of your reduce functions do any summing. They either return the current item's `amountString`, or 0, or (as Pointy said) undefined. (So the final result of each reduce would be based entirely on the last item in the array.)

Answer (score 1):

```
var sumInvoices = item.invoices.reduce(function(sumInvoices, elem) {
            if (elem !== null && elem.invoice !== null) {
                return +(elem.invoicedNet && elem.invoicedNet.amountString ? elem.invoicedNet.amountString : 0);
            }
            return sumInvoices;  // <--------------------add this
        }, 0);
```

As Pointy commented, you need to add a return statement. To avoid any other issues, you should add areturn statement to each of the reduce you are using as well.